# What would be the meaning of "You give me the awful impression […] of someone who hasn't read any of the arguments against your position ever."?

Tags: grammar, spoken-english, syntax

As a non native speaker I am facing trouble understanding one of the famous quotes from Christopher Hitchens,

> "You give me the awful impression, I hate to have to say it, of someone who hasn't read any of the arguments against **your** position ever."

Can anyone explain, why Hitchens said, “against **your** position” instead “against **their/his/her** position”? Is there any grammatical problem or not?

Comment: This question was moved from other [site](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599565/372000) as suggested.

Comment: (2) means what it says. He feels he has to say it, but reluctantly.

Comment: There are multiple questions here. The issue of whether it should be "your position" or "his/her/their position" is interesting, although I think there are similar questions here or on ELU. The question about "the impression"/"an impression" is separate, but relates to the usual distinction between particular/specific and general/vague. And "I hate to have to say it" is used literally; it isn't clear what the OP's problem is; most likely it's the use of "have to" as an auxiliary.

Comment: "**You** give me the awful impression, I hate to have to say it, of someone who hasn't read any of the arguments against **your position** ever." The "someone" is referring to "you", i.e. "You are someone who hasn't read arguments against your position."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to phrase it the way you suggest, with "his/her/their position" to match the third person "someone". If Hitchens had been writing, rather than speaking, he would not have phrased it the way he did.

Hitchens's version, read literally, means some person who hasn't read the arguments *against Hitchens's opponent's* position, which is still accurate, but an odd thing to say.

Hitchens is conflating two ideas here, both of which fit the situation. One is your improved version of the sentence, and the other is this:

> You give me the awful impression **that *you* haven't** read any of the arguments against **your** position ever.

He matched the first part of one with the last part of the other, but it ended up sounding OK enough. I doubt the average native speaker noticed.